# install php 5.2.X on fedora 13

Tags: php, fedora

Where can i get php 5.2.X for fedora 13
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-php-on-centos-red-hat-rhel/ try above link

Comment: I flagged this answer for deletion because it is just a link to a tutorial, rather than an answer to the question. Answers should be self-contained, i.e. still be useful even without any links.